# Is there a way to publish a AS3 based Flash projector that will run on a PowerPC Mac?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using AS3 to author my project. I tried to publish as Flash Player 9 and this didn't work. I can't go down to Flash Player 8 because that predates AS3.

Comment: @weltraumpirat : Download the Flex SDK and run it with Eclipse?

Comment: @weltraumpirat - can you move your comment to an answer? I want to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open your SWF in the Flash Player on your PowerPC, then save as projector. The project has to be exported to run with the same Flash version, though - perhaps you have to use a different SDK?

If it isn't possible to target Flash 9 with your current version, try the Flex 3 SDK. You can [download](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3) it for free and run the compiler using a build tool like Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc., from your IDE (FlashDevelop, FlashBuilder, FDT, etc.) or directly from the command line / prompt.