# Control Flash Player version in a Mac projector app?

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

I'm using Flash CS6 to build a Mac projector app. The app is crashing on OS X 10.5.8, and I think it's because the projector is including Flash Player 11.4, which only runs on OS X 10.6+.

My question is: how do I control the version of the player embedded in the projector app?

I've tried targeting Flash Player 10.3 and 9 in the publish settings, but as far as I can guess, that only changes the version of playerglobal.swc used in compiling movie.swf.

Comment: My guess is you probably should export from a different([older projector](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html) app).

Answer (score 1):

Open the plain SWF in any older standalone player, then save as projector from there. There is a similar older question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183268/is-there-a-way-to-publish-a-as3-based-flash-projector-that-will-run-on-a-powerpc).

Comment: +1 for a workable idea, but I was looking for a way to do this from the Flash IDE's "publish" action.

Comment: The IDE supports only one Player version at a time. You can exchange that, but then you'll always publish to that version, and have the same problem again when publishing other projects.  With my solution, you can keep as many different player versions around, as you like, while always having the most recent (i.e. bug-fixed) player for reference while you work in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more tinkering, the solution seems to be rather simple: the player embedded in the projector is a copy of the player in Flash IDE install directory (ie, `/Applications/Adobe Flash CS6/Players/Flash Player`). I swapped out that file with the 10.3 version from [Adobe Flash Player Downloads](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) and presto, my Mac app embedded the 10.3 player.